# summarise_each in R applied to same column but different groupings

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summary

```
df1<- structure(list(race = c("White", "White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "White", "White", "Hispanic", "White", "White"), gender = c("M","M","M","F","M","F","F","F","M","F"), success = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10"))

Row    race   gender success
1     White      M       1
2     White      M       1
3  Hispanic      M       0
4  Hispanic      F       1
5  Hispanic      M       0
6     White      F       0
7     White      F       1
8  Hispanic      F       0
9     White      M       0
10    White      F       1
```

Above is my data. What I would like to do is include a column that includes success counts by gender and another that includes success counts by race. The following works independently, but I can't get them to work together:

```
RaceSuccess<- df1 %>% group_by(race)%>%summarise(racesuc = sum(success))
```

This gives the success totals for each race in a new column

```
GenderSuccess <- df1 %>% group_by(gender)%>%summarise(gensuc=sum(success))
```

This gives me the success totals for each gender in a new column.

However, I can't figure out how to add the two new columns to the end in one piece of code. I can't add another pipe after the summarise function so I am hoping that someone can help me out.

Comment: Maybe two `mutate()'s` instead?

Comment: I wasn't able to put summarise within the mutate

Comment: I was able to `group_by(gender)%>%mutate(gensuc=sum(success))%>%group_by(race)%>%mutate(racesuc=sum(success))` and that seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt at a general function that uses tidyeval to find the sum of values in one column grouped successively by any number of other columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

fnc = function(data, outcome, ...) {

  groups=enquos(...)
  outcome=enquo(outcome)

  map(groups, ~ data %>% 
        group_by(!!.x) %>% 
        summarise(!!sym(paste0(quo_text(.x), "_", quo_text(outcome))) := sum(!!outcome))) %>% 
    c(list(data), .) %>% 
    reduce(left_join)

}
```

Now run the function:

```
fnc(df1, outcome=success, race, gender)
```

> ```
>        race gender success race_success gender_success
> 1     White      M       1            4              2
> 2     White      M       1            4              2
> 3  Hispanic      M       0            1              2
> 4  Hispanic      F       1            1              3
> 5  Hispanic      M       0            1              2
> 6     White      F       0            4              3
> 7     White      F       1            4              3
> 8  Hispanic      F       0            1              3
> 9     White      M       0            4              2
> 10    White      F       1            4              3
> ```

```
fnc(mtcars, outcome=am, cyl, gear, vs)
```

> ```
>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl_am gear_am vs_am
> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      3       8     6
> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      3       8     6
> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      8       8     7
> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      3       0     7
> ...
> 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2      8       5     7
> 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      2       5     6
> 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6      3       5     6
> 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8      2       5     6
> 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2      8       8     7
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave()` within a `mutate()` step to save having to use multiple `group_by()`s.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
mutate(
  RaceSuccess = ave(success, race, FUN=sum),
  GenderSuccess = ave(success, gender, FUN=sum)
)
```